# Discord.py button interaction message delete

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, interaction

```
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Delete"))
    await interaction.delete()
```

When I press it it says interation failed.

Comment: I think that's discord's problem and not your code's

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is because `await interaction.delete()` doesn't delete anything. According to the docs for [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for), it returns

> Returns no arguments, a single argument, or a tuple of multiple arguments that mirrors the parameters passed in the event reference."

If you want to delete the original message, get where you sent the message as
`msg = await ctx.send("stuff here")`
and delete with `await msg.delete()`
Your bot has to have Manage Messages even to delete their own messages though.

Comment: How do you recommend I get the first message?

Comment: Where do you sent the first message?
Assign that to a variable and then call msg.delete()